# Що ж таке "істерн"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники, неологізми

Зустрілося у двох статтях слово **`істерн`**:

[Романтичний *`істерн`* про Тараса Шевченка знімають в Україні і Казахстані](https://hromadskeradio.org/programs/rankova-hvylya/romantychnyy-istern-pro-tarasa-shevchenka-znimayut-v-ukrayini-i-kazahstani)

> Андрій Куликов: Фабула і жанр фільму?
>
> Олександр Денисенко: Це романтичний **`істерн`**.

[Перший український *`істерн`*: як екранізують роман Жадана "Ворошиловград"](http://life.pravda.com.ua/culture/2017/08/8/225772/)

> Тож це буде вестерн. Точніше його різновид – **`істерн`**, адже дія
>   відбувається у східній півкулі.
>
> <...>
>
> А нині починає вимальовуватися жанр **`істерну`** та основний конфлікт
>   фільму.

Результат пошуку значення не тішить: лише статті у Вікіпедії (російській та англійській версіях).

> [И́стерн](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD)
>   (англ. eastern — «восточный») или остерн (нем. ostern) — жанр
>   приключенческих фильмов, названный так по аналогии с вестерном. Иногда
>   среди западных критиков для обозначения подобных фильмов, снятых в
>   СССР, использовался пренебрежительный термин «борщ-вестерн» (по
>   аналогии с итальянскими «спагетти-вестернами»).
>
> [The Ostern (Eastern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostern) or Red Western (also known as "Borscht Western") was the Soviet Union and
>   Eastern Bloc countries' take on the Western. The term refers to two
>   related genres:
>
> Proper Red Westerns, set in America's 'Wild West', such as Lemonade
>   Joe (Czechoslovakia, 1964), or the East-German The Sons of Great Bear
>   (1966) or The Oil, the Baby and the Transylvanians (Romania, 1981), or
>   A Man from the Boulevard des Capucines (USSR, 1987), involving
>   radically different themes and genres. These were mostly produced in
>   Eastern European countries like East Germany and Czechoslovakia,
>   rather than USSR.
>
> Easterns (Osterns), set usually on the steppes or Asian parts of the
>   USSR, especially during the Russian Revolution or the following Civil
>   War. Examples of these include The Elusive Avengers (1966) and its two
>   sequels, White Sun of the Desert (1969), Dauria (1971), At Home among
>   Strangers (1974), The Burning Miles (1957), The Bodyguard (1979), and
>   The Sixth (1981). While obviously influenced by Westerns, Easterns
>   form a specific genre. The word "Ostern" is derived from the German
>   word Ost, meaning "East".

Зважаючи на пояснення Вікіпедії, можна зрозуміти контекстне значення у статті про екранізацію роману Сергія Жадана.

Щодо **`істерну`** про Шевченка  не все так очевидно, далебі.

**То що ж таке `істерн` і чи доречне його вживання в контексті наведених вище прикладів?**

Comment: Я б сказав, що *eastern*, як і *western*, є суто чиїмись влучними означеннями. В сучасній інтернет-субкультурі це називається *forced meme*. Тільки згодом слово *western* стало широко вживаним, і його змістовне значення стало більш-менш чітко визначеним. А значення слова *eastern* у кожного — своє. А якщо так, то значить, і відповіді на запитання нема і бути не може. Моя думка — Close/Opinion-based, але почекаю, поки висловляться інші.

Comment: @bytebuster, гм, а як же стаття у англомовній Вікі? І ще ось таке знайшла: [Filmgenre Eastern Definition - Erläuterung - Erklärung des Film-Genres](http://www.film-genres.de/eastern.shtml)

Comment: @bytebuster, і ось ще: [Eastern westerns : film and genre outside and inside Hollywood](https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/11889004). Я розумію, що за цими посиланнями можна знайти пояснення значення англійського слова, а не українського. Але, може, це свідчить на користь того, що це вже не зовсім *forced meme*? Питання в тому, чи правильно використовують в українській мові (зважаючи на відсутність суто українського відповідника)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мені здається, може бути й доречним.

Я розумію слово *істерн* таким чином:

- це або фільми про [Дикий Захід](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4), **знятий** у країнах, які традиційно відносять до Сходу, а не до [Заходу](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F), в тому числі, наприклад, в СРСР чи сучасних країнах колишнього СРСР; приклад — [«Сини Великої Ведмедиці»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%96_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC));
- або фільм, події якого відбуваються на Сході, але антураж якого є типовим для класичних [вестернів](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD); наприклад — [«Свій серед чужих, чужий серед своїх»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%85,_%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%97%D1%85).

Я не знаю, який сюжет і антураж у наданих Вами прикладах; тим більше, що антураж (і його влучання в певну категорію) — поняття суб'єктивне; але цілком визнаю за мовцем право використати це слово для підкреслення певних особливостей твору.

Єдине що мені здається нелогічним — це те, чому раптом Україна (навіть східна її частина, де, здається, розгортаються події «Ворошиловграда» Сергія Жадана) належить до Східного світу. З іншого боку, Україну, як країну Східної Європи і колишнього СРСР, часто просто за інерцією сприймають як пост-СРСР — тим більше, що події «Ворошиловграда», здається, вимальовуються саме на тлі руїн СРСР. Щодо фільму «Тарас. Повернення», то його події, здається, взагалі відбуваються в Казахстані, куди Шевченка було відправлено у зіслання.

P.S.: Якби мене попросили розшифрувати, що таке «класичний антураж вестернів», то я би, мабуть, сказав, що це твори про боротьбу сильних і мужніх людей (часто дихотомічно поділених на «хороших» і «поганих») в умовах «дикого» суспільства (коли органи правосуддя не працюють і кожен сам за себе, слабкі не виживають) з певним ореолом романтично-героїчного пафосу навколо персонажів. Зазвичай події відбуваються в минулому — за широкого розповсюдження вогнепальної зброї, але до широкого розповсюдження індивідуальних автомобілів — в сільській (часто степовій) місцині і теплому (але нелегкому) кліматі. Також, мабуть, умовою має бути не абсолютна дикість людької цивілізації — радше «острови» дикості у світі, що в окремих своїх частинах є досить розвиненим («десь там є міста»), а не первісний рівень розвитку усієї цивілізації — і на тлі цього підкреслюється мужність і рішучість героїв.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, «Бажана», оце так :). Я навіть думав «ой, треба з цим не помилитися» — і таки помилився :).

Comment: Все ок :) Мені, до слова, більш зрозуміле вживання *істерн* в контексті екранізації Жадана. Це хоч якось "вписується" в умовний поділ захід(няки)/схід(няки) або північ/південь (це, до речі, властиво не тільки в українських реаліях). А от із Шевченком трохи складніше. Принаймні, для мого розуміння :) Дякую за відповідь!

Comment: Може, там Шевченко буде на коні відстрілюватися від переслідувачів і накидати ласо на кривдників казахських селян, хто знає

Comment: @ata_zh, :), судячи з [трейлеру](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnG-Rjphx5I), ні. Але, мені здається, і вестерн не обов'язково настільки героїчний; хоча найчастіше справді настільки. Але коли, типу, просто боротьба мужньої людини у певних умовах — може, й теж у широкому розумінні вестерн.

Comment: @ata_zh, щоб був істерн/вестерн за Шевченком, слід екранізувати "Гайдамаки" :)

Answer (score 3):

Наразі вже є стаття в [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD) (українською) про істерн:

> Пригодницький фільм, дія якого відбувається переважно в Середній Азії
>   чи на **Кавказі** і головно в період Громадянської війни в Російські
>   Імперії.

Ну а як відомо - Шевченко певний період свого житття провів на Кавказі. На жаль, не читав "Ворошиловград", але на скільки мені відомо - Ворошиловград - це давніша назва Луганська і знаходився він в Дикому полі (не знаходите паралелі із Диким заходом?). Крім того, на Вікіпедії можна знайти статті як про [перший](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81._%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F), так і про [другий фільми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC,_2018)#%D0%A1%D1%8E%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82), і там вказано, що їхній жанр - істерн. Додам ще, одну цитату із Вікіпедії:

> Фільми цього жанру мають традиційні стилістичні риси вестерну: «добрі»
>   й «погані» герої, погоні і перестрілки, коні і револьвери тощо.

Отож можемо зробити висновок, що справді існує такий жанр кіно, однак саме слово є запозиченим із англійської мови.